# Symfony, Google analytics: ga is not defined

Tags: javascript, symfony, google-analytics

I am trying to use Google analytics in my project but it keeps throwing out an error, here is the stack :

```
web.js?v=62:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined <br>
    at l (web.js?v=62:26) <br>
    at Object.calculatorInteraction (web.js?v=62:26) <br>
    at vendors.js?v=62:39 <br>
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) <br>
    at vendors.js?v=62:39 <br>
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) <br>
    at ae (vendors.js?v=62:39) <br>
    at vendors.js?v=62:39 <br>
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) <br>
    at te (vendors.js?v=62:39) <br>
```

I am working on Symfony 4.2.11. here is the code snippet

```
export let googleEvents;
let linkedinEvents;
let facebookEvents;
const googleEvent = (eventCategory, eventAction, eventLabel = null, eventValue = null) => {
    let object = { eventCategory, eventAction }
    if (eventLabel) {
        object = { ...object, eventLabel }
    }
    if (eventValue) {
        object = { ...object, eventValue }
    }
    ga('send', 'event', object);
}
```

I guess something is wrong on the: `ga('send', 'event', object)`; line.

Comment: So where is `ga` supposed to be defined? You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Can you show us the `webpack.config.js` ? Where this script is loaded ? Give us more informations about the script and where/how is it loaded.